# Precision and AUROC for which class values

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees, svm, k-nn

I am a newbie in reading research paper and implementing it by myself. I went through the paper [Breast Cancer Survival Prediction from Imbalanced Dataset with Machine Learning Algorithms](https://www.philstat.org.ph/index.php/MSEA/article/view/125).

Can anyone please summarize the paper for me? I cannot understand the Table 2:
Performance of ML algorithms with data sampling techniques. As I am a learner I can not understand, are those precision and AUROc for class(Status) value "Alive" or "Dead"?

Thank you.